# Azure datafactory issue with ARM templated

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using azure devops release pipelines to deploy to azure data factory, but then there seem to be limit for number of characters in ARM template. I am getting error as below.

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The number of template input parameters limit exceeded. Limit: '256' and actual: '274'.

Could someone help is there any way other than reducing the characters in the template?

Comment: this is not a character limit, it is a parameter limit. you should try breaking it down to have fewer parameters.... also if you would like it better input you should provide the ARM template you are attempting. Help us help you. :)

Comment: Hey Rob.. agree with you, this is parameter issue...is there any other alternative ? like to use nested template concept?

Comment: It would be really helpful to know what the source of all these parameters are... is it from triggers? Linked Services? Global Parameters? etc

Comment: Hey Trent, yes its from triggers and linked services

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the number of parameters you have by taking advantage of dynamic Linked service and Datasets. Triggers can also lead to many Parameters in the ARM Template. It may be that having this many parameters is unavoidable, if that is the case you should consider splitting the workload into multiple Data Factories. Without seeing your exact ARM Template it is hard to know how to help.

Comment: splitting is not an option in our case..is there any other way we can reduce the parameters? like can we use nested template concept? will it work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/best-practices#template-limits

Comment: "You're also limited to:

256 parameters
256 variables
800 resources (including copy count)
64 output values
24,576 characters in a template expression
You can exceed some template limits by using a nested template."  So I'd think it may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation you see it's because of the parameters you have been declaring. Please try to have your parameters in the below format. You can reduce the parameters having objects.

```html
"parameters": {
  "<parameter-name>" : {
    "type" : "<type-of-parameter-value>",
    "defaultValue": "<default-value-of-parameter>",
    "allowedValues": [ "<array-of-allowed-values>" ],
    "minValue": <minimum-value-for-int>,
    "maxValue": <maximum-value-for-int>,
    "minLength": <minimum-length-for-string-or-array>,
    "maxLength": <maximum-length-for-string-or-array-parameters>,
    "metadata": {
      "description": "<description-of-the parameter>"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the doc for the same : [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters)

Comment: have tried this way out..but still the parameters are huge... do we have any other option like nested template concept?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters, you can customize your ARM's parameter's template by editing `arm-template-parameters-definition.json`.

From my understanding, this file will tell your npm build tasks which config in your json files should be parameterized into your `ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json`.

In general, you can try to remove some configs in your `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` and compare the parameters count in your `ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json`. The trade-off is some configs will be hardcoded in your `ARMTemplateForFactory.json`.

This works for me, and I managed to reduce the parameter count from 300+ to 100.